# Flutter Populating List<String> using for loop

Tags: flutter, list, firebase, for-loop, arraylist

I want to get all the document IDs in my firebase and store it in List but I'm only getting one of the documents. Here is my execution

[PrtSc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO6QZ.jpg)

my code

```
Future saveUserCart(User currentUser) async
{
  List<String> IDs = [];

  Future getDocs() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userCart").get();
    for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {

      var itemIDs = querySnapshot.docs[i];

      print(itemIDs.id);

      IDs = [itemIDs.id];
    }
    print(IDs);
  }
  getDocs();
}
```

Fix my problem and learn something

Answer (score 1):

Try IDs.add(itemIDs.id); instead of IDs=[itemIDs.id];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the code in question is creating a new list and assigning it to the last id. When we use add method we can get all ids from the documents.

```
Future saveUserCart(User currentUser) async
{
  List<String> IDs = [];

  Future getDocs() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(currentUser.uid)
        .collection("userCart").get();
    for (int i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length; i++) {

      var itemIDs = querySnapshot.docs[i];

      print(itemIDs.id);

      IDs.add(itemIDs.id);
    }
    print(IDs);
  }
  getDocs();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just Example,

you can use base on your requirements. For gettings "ID" you don't need to use for loop, use "map" functions.

```
 var data = [{'key':'abc', 'id':1},{ 'key': 'xyz', 'id': 2}];
 var mapData = data.map((res) => res['id']);
 print("mapData => ${mapData.toList()}");
```

Expected Output,

```
mapData => [1, 2]
```

Maybe, it will help you.

Comment: I'm confused about how to apply these to my code. But Thank you very much

Comment: dynamic docs = querySnapshot.docs;
var mapData = docs.map((res) => res['id']);
print("mapData => ${mapData.toList()}");

**Try with this @SPYTheman **
I did not try but hope it will work for you.

Comment: It's working Sir, Thank you but I have a question, Why can't I store it in sharedPreferences!.setStringList it said 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>'

Comment: If your "docs" Array object multi dimensions look like this [{"id": "1", "key":"abc"}] then you have to declared 'List<dynamic>'. -------

And If your array looks like single dimensions ['1','2','3']  then you have to declared List<String>.  @SPYTheman

Comment: I suggest just declared "dynamic" instead of "List<>".